# mousedown event not working for kendolistview buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendoListview.
   I have given my listview like,

```
<div id="listview"></div>
 var listview = $("#listview").kendoListView({
    selectable: true,
    navigatable: false,
    editable: true,
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    editTemplate: kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html()),
 }).data("kendoListView");
```

in the edit template I have given like,

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="editTemplate">
    <div>
    <table style="width:500px">
     <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" id="firstName"/></td>
     </tr> 

     </table>
     <div class="edit-buttons">
       <input type="button" class="k-update" id = "save1" value="save"/>
       <input type="button" class="k-cancel-button" id = "cancel1" value="cancel"/>
     </div>
   </div>
</script>
```

if I give mouse down event for save button it is not firing.

```
$("#save1").mousedown(function (e) {
       alert("In mouse down");
 });
```

If I define the button out side listview then this event is firing.what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to be related to the fact that when you set `mousedown` event handler there is no element with `id` `save1` since this is part of the template and created when you enter the edition mode.

So either you run:

```
$("#save1").mousedown(function (e) {
    alert("In mouse down");
});
```

each time you enter edition mode or you use jQuery [`live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#listview").on("mousedown", "#save1", function (e) {
       alert("In mouse down");
 });
```

See a JSFiddle implementing this here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6vac4/